# Value keeps returning as 0 and don't know why

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game of blackjack with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, this is what I have so far, what it should do is get the players and computers initial hands and print it to the screen. But the value of the hands always returns as 0 and I'm not sure why... any help would be appreciated, here's a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/KR9jJ/

//When the window loads, position the canvas to the center of the screen both vertically and horizontally

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * 0.8;
    var canvasHeight = canvasWidth / 2;
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
    canvas.style.top = (viewportHeight - canvasHeight) / 2 + "px";
    canvas.style.left = (viewportWidth - canvasWidth) / 2 + "px";
};
```

//function for random number generator 1-13

```
function random() {
    var number = (Math.random()*13)+1;
    return number;
}

function rank() {
    var randomCard = random(); 
    var output = "randomCard";
    switch (randomCard) {
        case 1:
            output = "Ace";
            break;
        case 2:
            output = "Two";
            break;
        case 3:
            output = "Three";
            break;
        case 4:
            output = "Four";
            break;
        case 5:
            output = "Five";
            break;
        case 6:
            output = "Six";
            break;
        case 7:
            output = "Seven";
            break;
        case 8:
            output = "Eight";
            break;
        case 9:
            output = "Nine";
            break;
        case 10:
            output = "Ten";
            break;
        case 11:
            output = "Jack";
            break;
        case 12:
            output = "Queen";
            break;
        case 13:
            output = "King";
        break;
    }
return output;
 }
```

//function to return the value of a card based on the random result

```
function value(randomCard) {
var output = 0;
    if (randomCard === ("Ace")) {
        output = 11;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Two")) {
        output = 2;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Three")) {
        output = 3;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Four")) {
        output = 4;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Five")) {
        output = 5;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Six")) {
        output = 6;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Seven")) {
        output = 7;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Eight")) {
        output = 8;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Nine")) {
        output = 9;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Ten")) {
        output = 10;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Jack")) {
        output = 10;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("Queen")) {
        output = 10;
    }

    if (randomCard === ("King")) {
        output = 10;
    }
return output;
}
```

//Specify the players and computers default hand

```
var playerHand = 0;
var compHand = 0;
```

//deal initial hands for both computer and player

```
var playerFirstCard = rank();
var playerCardOne = value(playerFirstCard);

var compFirstCard = rank();
var compCardOne = value(compFirstCard);

var playerSecondCard = rank();
var playerCardTwo = value(playerSecondCard);
playerHand = playerHand + (playerCardOne+playerCardTwo);

var compSecondCard = rank();
var compCardTwo = value(compSecondCard);
compHand = compHand + (compCardOne+compCardTwo);
```

//Show players and comps hand

```
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = playerHand;
document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = compHand;
```

PLEASE NOTE: NO jQuery suggestions please.

Comment: you need to break this down into units, and then test the units. and only later put the already tested units together.

Comment: im not sure of the problem about why u get 0.but im guessing that Math.floor((Math.random()*13)+1) will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rank()` always returns "randomCard", because `(Math.random()*13)+1` will come out to something like 9.1245986, not a whole number.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you! so the round function will fix that I take it?

Math.round(Math.random()*13)+1) ?

Comment: Fixed it now, thank you... will accept as soon as I can

Comment: @Daniel Morgan you want to use `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 2):

At rank function.
Add floor function from Math labs. Your random is decimal while you check if your number is natural.

```
var randomCard = Math.floor(random());
```